# How to use phpThumb() in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, phpthumb

I am trying to use phpThumb() which i downloaded from http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net in zend framework
I like it the way it generates thumbnails and resized images. Its simple to use. I just need to add an image tag to generate image as defined width and height:

```
<img src="phpThumb.php?src=image.jpg&w=100"/>
```

I would like to use it in zend framework. If anybody is using it in zend framework, could you please show me the way to use it. Currently I m planning to place the phpThumb() library inside public folder and calling it as

```
<img src="public/phpThumb.php?src=image.jpg&w=100"/>
```

Is this a good idea? I would also like to know how good is it? What are the security holes if any?

Answer (score 0):

In my projects I place phpThumb in *library/Vendor/PHPThumb* and just use:

```
$file = 'PATH_TO_FILE';
$thumb = Vendors_PHPThumb_Thumb::create($file);
$thumb->resize($width, $height)->save($file);
```

this will resize source file